Connect to Postgresql database host in a docker container from outside
I have very little knowledge of docker, so I apologize in advance if my question seems silly.
My database is in a docker container and I'd like to access it from my API, which is not in a container but locally on my machine.
So I need to access my database from outside my docker.
Here's my docker-compose file:
version: '3.9'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:16.2
    restart: always
    shm_size: 128mb
    container_name: db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=sa
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
    ports:
      - 33306:3306

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8080

From my API, I specify the following url:
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:33306/sa

I always get the same error despite my numerous tests:
The connection attempt failed

My docker is running correctly, I can access to my database from the docker container and create Table etc.
My problem is only the connection from outside.
I also tried to connect with telnet with this command:
telnet 127.0.0.1 33306

And here is my error :
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.

Also I'm using this command to run my docker :
docker-compose up -d            

Can you help me understand what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks by advance.

Docker automatically maps the default PostgreSQL server port which is 5432, not 3306.

Thank you so much! That was the solution! Just to know it for the next time, where can I find this information? I didn't see it on the postgres docker hub.

Every database system exposes its default port by default (MySQL 3306, PostgreSQL 5432, MongoDB 27017, etc.). You can find this information on each database documentation website. Since you are using PostgreSQL inside a container, the better option for you is to keep the default port inside the container and map it to the port you want on your localhost.

Okay I got it! Thanks for your explanations!
